# C++ with unordered_set container, cant make with use of deleted function

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to code an online open sourse class with c++. I use the unordered_set container in lab1. However everytime I want to 'make'. It brought up with following error;

Here is my code;

I create a class and want to push it into unordered_set.

```
class Input_data {
  private:
    std::string _data;
    uint64_t _index;
    bool _eof;

  public:
    Input_data(const std::string &data, const uint64_t index, const bool eof) : _data(data), _index(index), _eof(eof) {}

    bool operator<(Input_data &B) {
        if (this->_index < B._index) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

```
class StreamReassembler {
  private:
    size_t _current_index = 0;
    size_t _current_volume = 0;
    ByteStream _output;  //!< The reassembled in-order byte stream
    size_t _capacity;    //!< The maximum number of bytes
    std::unordered_set<Input_data> _unsorted_data;
 public:
    StreamReassembler::StreamReassembler(const size_t capacity) : _output(capacity), _capacity(capacity), _unsorted_data() {}

    ...

}
```

Here is the error:

```
In constructor ‘StreamReassembler::StreamReassembler(size_t)’:
/mnt/hgfs/AllShare/Cs144/libsponge/stream_reassembler.cc:15:103: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unordered_set<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_set() [with _Value = Input_data; _Hash = std::hash<Input_data>; _Pred = std::equal_to<Input_data>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Input_data>]’
   15 |  size_t capacity) : _output(capacity), _capacity(capacity), _unsorted_data() {}
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

my g++ and gcc version is 11
I'm a beginner of c++, I think it might be a simple question however I googled 2 days without finding a way to pass the error. Looking for some help.

Comment: You've implemented `operator <` which is not used by `unordered_set` and did not implement hash and equal functions which are required.

Comment: So if I want to use unsorderd_set with a new class. I must implement equal and hash function?

Comment: `operator <` is used by normal `set`, because it maintains strict order of elements, so yes, for `unordered_set` you need to implement hash and equal

Comment: @KEIFTHYANG Don't forget that these function must be `const` with `const` parameters. That was a mistake with your `operator<`

Comment: btw `if (condition) return true; else return false;` is written as `return condition;`

Comment: @john thanks, I kind of getting c++ const very strict language....

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number lol, my bad, I was too frustrated yesterday

Comment: CS144? The "you need to be very comfortable with C++" networking course? Perhaps you should start at the beginning, with an introduction to C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo yea, I'm trying to do both things in the same time, I just finished an online c++ course without any practicing, really hard to do both things together....